# Python - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fire'

Tags: python

I'm learning to make a basic neural network and I'm trying to make one that can add numbers together in python, but I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tomas/Desktop/projects/neuralnetwork/main.py", line 37, in <module>
    class Main:
  File "C:/Users/tomas/Desktop/projects/neuralnetwork/main.py", line 76, in Main
    out.fire()
  File "C:/Users/tomas/Desktop/projects/neuralnetwork/main.py", line 23, in fire
    i.fire()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'fire'
```

I'm new to python so forgive me if I made some obvious mistake.

Code:

```
class Synapse:
    origin = None
    weight, learningRate = 0.5, 0.25

    def __init__(self, origin):
        self.origin = origin

    def adjust_weight(self, result, expected):
        self.weight *= self.learningRate * (expected - result)


class Neuron:
    threshold, output = None, None
    inputs = []

    def __init__(self, threshold, output):
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.output = output

    def fire(self):
        weighed_input = 0
        for i in self.inputs:
            i.fire()
            weighed_input += i.weight * i.origin.output
        if weighed_input >= self.threshold:
            self.output = weighed_input
        else:
            self.output = 0

    def connect_synapse(self, *synapse):
        self.inputs.append(synapse)

    def clear_synapses(self):
        self.inputs = []

class Main:
    training_data = [[[1, 2], [3]],
                     [[2, 0], [2]],
                     [[1, 1], [2]],
                     [[3, 0], [3]],
                     [[3, 1], [4]]]

    src1 = Neuron(0, None)
    src2 = Neuron(0, None)

    hid1 = Neuron(1, None)
    hid2 = Neuron(1, None)

    out = Neuron(0, None)

    syn1 = Synapse(src1)
    syn2 = Synapse(src2)
    syn3 = Synapse(hid1)
    syn4 = Synapse(hid2)

    while True:
        error_count = 0

        hid1.clear_synapses()
        hid2.clear_synapses()
        hid1.connect_synapse(syn1, syn2)
        hid2.connect_synapse(syn1, syn2)

        out.clear_synapses()
        out.connect_synapse(syn3, syn4)

        for i in range(0, 5):
            input1 = training_data[i][0][0]
            input2 = training_data[i][0][1]
            expected = training_data[i][1][0]

            src1.output = input1
            src2.output = input2

            out.fire()
            result = out.output
            if result != expected:
                error_count += 1
                syn1.adjust_weight(result, expected)
                syn2.adjust_weight(result, expected)

             print("Expected ", expected, "\nGot ", result, "\nError count: ", error_count, "\n\n")

        if error_count == 0:
            break
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't Java. You don't need to stick everything in a class. Also, defining variables at class scope creates class variables, not instance variables.

Comment: Yeah, I'm used to Java and I haven't coded much in Python

Comment: What did you think `i.fire()` was going to do? Why did you expect `i` to have a `fire` method?

Comment: You don't call anything in the given code, could you show an example of it's use?

Comment: `i` is a pair of synapses.

Comment: `self.inputs` is a list of tuples, so if `i` is in `self.inputs` it’s going to be a tuple and not have a `fire` method.

Comment: Since only in the connect_synapse method I append a Synapse instance to inputs, I assume that input is gonna contain only Synapse instances which have a fire method

Comment: @Ryan Replacing "inputs = []" with "inputs = None" still returns the same error

Comment: Should `connect_synapse(a, b)` be like `connect_synapse(a); connect_synapse(b)`? If so, use `self.inputs.extend(synapses)` instead of `append`. Right now you’re telling Python – by writing `*synapse` – to put all of the arguments passed into a tuple.

Comment: @Ryan doing that gives me the error "AttributeError: 'Synapse' object has no attribute 'fire'" in the same line

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for the help Ryan :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

def connect_synapse(self, *synapse):
            self.inputs.append(synapse)

This is receiving multiple arguments "*synapse" as a tuple.
The tuple is then being appended to your list.
You should consider using [extend](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: Doing that gives me the error "AttributeError: 'Synapse' object has no attribute 'fire'" in the same line

Comment: Should "fire" be in the Synapse class then ?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized the error:

Instead of i.fire() I should use i.origin.fire() and instead of self.inputs.append(synapse) i should use self.inputs.extend(synapse)

Answer (score 0):

Your `i.fire()` is not working because `self.inputs[]` of the Class `Neuron` contains `Synapses` and not other `Neurons`.